# How to force an html form accept only inputs with value greater then ""?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, get

my form:

```
<form action='assetSearch.php' method='GET'>
      <input type='text' name='city' value="NewYork">
      <input type='text' name='street' value="">
      <input type='submit' name='submitBtn'>
</form>
```

after submitting, my url looks like that:

```
http://localhost/www/Self%20Projects/public/assetSearch.php?city=NewYork&street=
```

and this how I expect my url to look like:

```
http://localhost/www/Self%20Projects/public/assetSearch.php?city=NewYork
```

the input fields does not have to be required. basically I just don't want to get an empty values to _GET array, and I want to make the url look cleaner.

Comment: But that is not how it is defined through the RFC...

Comment: If you want that you'd have to do it via js and add the fitlers to your url that way

Comment: Your question content doesn't really match the title. Are you actually asking how to make a field required in the form?

Comment: the input fields does'nt have to be required. basically i just dont want to get an empty value to GET array and make the url cleaner

Comment: Well it's not really necessary, users don't take that much notice and as someone mentioned above, you're going against the established standards. And it won't really make any practical difference to how the request is received on the server either. Personally I would advise you to spend your time on something actually productive for your application.